# Facebook Like Buttom with count don't update de count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have this facebook page: [LINK](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cal%C3%A7ados-Abruzzo/272754139414962)

And i want to implement multiple facebook like button on product page on site: [LINK](http://www.calcadosabruzzo.com.br/2012/catalogo.html)
When i click on "Like" Buttom, this aways shows "1" and when refresh the page, this count disapear.

for my product page i use:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and for buttons:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.calcadosabruzzo.com.br/2012/catalogo/1402.html" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="85" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui"></div>
```

for each phantom pages for the products i use these meta tags:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraph.org/schema/">

<head>
<title>Calçados Abruzzo - Ref.: 1402</title>

<meta property="og:title" content="Calçados Abruzzo - Ref.: 1402" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.calcadosabruzzo.com.br/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.calcadosabruzzo.com.br/2012/produtos/1402_5122_Marrom_montila.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Calçados Abruzzo" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="100002115061810" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.calcadosabruzzo.com.br/2012/catalogo.html">

</head><body></body></html>
```

i dont know where to get the APP_IP becouse the client make his page on facebook and dont make an APP

when i put the product page on Facebook Debug, show me these errors: [LINK](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.calcadosabruzzo.com.br%2F2012%2Fcatalogo.html)
How to solve this? Its the first time i use this Plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find few reports on this behaviour. I seems Facebook introduced a bug because even their reference where you can create like button gives errors. What people suggested is to make an app through [developers.facebook.com/apps](http://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Get the app_id from there and in the app settings under App Domain add your website (calcadosabruzzo.com.br).

For fb:admins you should add the app admin id (probably yours).

Hope this helps.